can't able use background-color css in playwright
i am not able to use background-color css property in python template using playwright package firstly,i tried apply inline css style="background-color:red", secondly used script tag,using js still not working and lastly i set html content when pdf is generated in playwright package in python template but the background color still not applied
with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch()
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.set_content(html_content, wait_until="networkidle")

        html_content = '
 footer_template = """
                <style>
                    .footer {
                        font-size: 10px;
                        text-align: center;
                        width: 100%;
                        margin: 10px 1cm 0 1cm;
                        font-family: "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
                        background-color:red;
                    }
                    .footer-content {
                        display: flex;
                        align-items: center;
                        justify-content: space-between;
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 100%;
                    }
                    .fw-bold {
                        font-weight: bold;
                    }
                </style>
                        <div class="footer">
                        <div class="footer-content">
                        <p class="fw-bold">Powered By TECHstile.in</p>
                        <p>This is a Computer Generated Invoice</p>
                        <p>{{invoice_number}}-
                        <strong><span class="pageNumber"></span>/<span class="totalPages"></span></strong>
                        </p>
                        </div>
                </div>
            """
 template = Template(footer_template)


Please share a complete, runnable [mcve]. What is html_content and how are you using template after you define it?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

i am not able to apply background color in my pdf i am trying to convert html to pdf using playwright package for template

page.set_content(html_content)
time.sleep(1)
page.evaluate('''() => {
const header = document.querySelector('header');
if (header) {
header.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue'; // Change this to your desired color
header.style.color = 'white'; // Change the text color to white
header.style.padding = '10px'; // Add some padding
header.style.fontSize = '20px'; // Change the font size
}
}''') using this header will be blurr but the background color not applied

You can add print_background=True in your python file where you are converting your HTML content to pdf, and simply add background-color property in your CSS to add background color in playwright pdf
